# mouseover only on one element (same class)

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm having problem making a color change & image change on mouseover(using Jquery, or using CSS if possible it doesnt metter), but I've a problem that only the first element get change, or all of them (using the ID/CLASS for every element for deisgn), now
this is my html, and CSS for my design

CSS:

```
#button_id {
    margin: 5px;
    display: block;
}

#button_nav {
    display: inline;
}

#button_img {
    background-image: url('images/left_nav_button.gif');
    width: 11px;
    height: 11px;
    float: left;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="button_id" class="button_id">
    <div id="button_nav"> 
        <div id="button_img" class="button_img"></div>
        <div id="button_name" class="button_name">Employment & skills</div>
        <div id="clear"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried using jQuery like this:

```
$(".button_id").mouseover(function() {
    $("#button_img").css('background-image', 'url(images/left_nav_button_hover.gif)');
    $(".button_id").css('color','#0365b9');
}).mouseout(function() {
    $(".button_img").css('background-image', 'url(images/left_nav_button.gif)');
    $(".button_id").css('color','#8C8C8C');
});
```

I tried to play with it and I got into 2 situations:

1. When everyone get a color changed + the background-image
2. Only the first div ( id="button_id" class="button_id" ) got change.

I tried, to switch and play with the class/id but couldn't solve it, I also tried using `$("#this")` it worked only with the color (because the image is other div, I also tried to use .children but I wasn't sure how to set it on other div, I tried something like

```
$(this).children(("#element")).css(..)
```

but it didn't work :(

Comment: mmm try to review your code, like this `.button_id` is kinda ugly (you call a class id). And did you use `$(document).ready()`?

Comment: I tried to play with it (.button_id or #button_id), and yes I did

Comment: What do you want exactly? Change the background of the current `.button_id`, change every div with this class, or change the first element matching this class?

Comment: change every div with this class, but only the specific div that the mouse is over him

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case you have given us, you don't need to use any javascript to do simple hover changes, since you area only doing CSS changes in them anyway:

CSS

```
.button_id {
    background: #000000 url(/path/to/image) top left no-repeat;
}
.button_id:hover {
    background: #ff0000 url(/path/to/image2) top left no-repeat;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="button_id" class="button_id">
    <div id="button_nav"> 
        <div id="button_img" class="button_img"></div>
        <div id="button_name" class="button_name">Employment & skills</div>
        <div id="clear"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you want to do non-css things, then you can use the function `hover()`:

```
jQuery( function($) {
    $('.button_id').hover(
        function() {
            // Do mouseover stuff here
        },
        function() {
            // Do mouseout stuff here
        }
});
```

Comment: the image is in other DIV ... I need to do changes in 2 div's

Comment: then you can do `.button_id:hover .div1` and `.button_id:hover .div2`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".button_id").hover(function() {
    $("#button_img", this).css('background-image', 'url(images/left_nav_button_hover.gif)');
    $(this).css('color', '#0365b9');
}, function() {
    $(".button_img", this).css('background-image', 'url(images/left_nav_button.gif)');
    $(this).css('color', '#8C8C8C');
   });
});
```

Comment: it doesnt change the images on Hover

Answer (score 0):

try using `mouseenter()` and `mouseleave()`

live demo [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/c3SFr/1/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="button_1" class="button_id">
    <div id="button_nav"> 
        <div id="button_img" class="button_img"></div>
        <div id="button_name" class="button_name">Employment & skills</div>
        <div id="clear"></div>
    </div>
</div><br/>
<div id="button_2" class="button_id">
    <div id="button_nav"> 
        <div id="button_img" class="button_img"></div>
        <div id="button_name" class="button_name">Contact Us</div>
        <div id="clear"></div>
    </div>
</div><br/>
<div id="button_3" class="button_id">
    <div id="button_nav"> 
        <div id="button_img" class="button_img"></div>
        <div id="button_name" class="button_name">Corporate Queries</div>
        <div id="clear"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.button_id {
    margin: 5px;
    display: block;
    border:1px dotted red;
}


#button_nav {

    display: inline;
}

#button_img {
    background-image: url('images/left_nav_button.gif');
    width: 11px;
    height: 11px;
    float: left;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
    $(".button_id").mouseenter(function() {
    $("#button_img", this).css('background-image', 'url(images/left_nav_button_hover.gif)');
    $(this).css('color', '#0365b9');
}).mouseleave(function() {
    $(".button_img", this).css('background-image', 'url(images/left_nav_button.gif)');
    $(this).css('color', '#8C8C8C');
   });
```

Comment: Is it fine or you require any thing else ? if so please describe it briefly.

Comment: hey, I got the exact same effect as you have in your demo.
I want the color change ONLY IN THE SPECIFIC DIV THAT THE MOUSE IS OVER HIM. and not on everyone.

thanks!

Comment: @user1927064 Uppercase won't change anything to the the comprehension of your problem

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, there are multiple `<div id="button_id" class="button_id">` containers..?

If so, that may be the problem - each `id` must be unique.  Try removing the `id`s and stick to classes (example at [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ABgF2/1/)).

Comment: it doesnt work, like u can see I changed into real images links and it doesnt change them
http://jsfiddle.net/ABgF2/3/

Comment: Sorry, I had edited my example shortly after posting to fix an error.  The revised example worked.  Applying those same fixes to the real image example seems to work - http://jsfiddle.net/ABgF2/4/

Answer (score 0):

I would ditch all of these efforts and use css sprites to do what you are trying to do, dont make things harder on yourself. Make the image exactly double the height place your hover image at the bottom. Then add that image as a background to your a href, then when the user hovers over your a href or div or whatever this works for everything. Add after that div :hover in your css.  Change the background-position to be bottom not top. Done.. If you need a demo I can drop one for you, but this is a sprite in a nutshell.

Comment: yes, but you forgot that I need 2 scripts with the :hover to act on 2 elements, "button_img" - to change background-image and "button_id" - to change color

Answer (score 0):

(First: since ID's must be unique, I assume that the html you posted in the question is also unique to your page)

Trying to figure out what you're actually looking for the code to do - not making too much sense of it to be honest. To change a single element:

```
<div id="button_id">
      <div id="button_nav"> 
            <div id="button_img"></div>
            <div id="button_name">Employment & skills</div>
            <div id="clear"></div>
      </div>
</div>

$("#button_id").mouseover(function() {
    $("#button_img").css('background-image', 'url(images/left_nav_button_hover.gif)');
    $("#button_id").css('color','#0365b9');
}).mouseout(function() {
    $("#button_img").css('background-image', 'url(images/left_nav_button.gif)');
    $("#button_id").css('color','#8C8C8C');
});
```

To change several elements you usually use classes, but then the css will look different:

```
.button_Class {
    /*foo*/
}

<div class="button_Class">

$(".button_Class").css('foo','bar');
```

etc.